# Global variable which may or may not change on each view Laravel 5.2

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

My requirement is simple. Since I am new to Laravel I don't know how exactly achieve it.

I have count of something say, I have count of pending friend requests. I have sidebar.blade.php in my view folder. This side bar is being called in all my other blade files like @include('sidebar').

Now, I want to display pending friend request count in my sidebar file, which will be practically displaying all over my website. How to achieve this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to create [view composer](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/views#view-composers). Create service provider which will register composer:

```
public function boot()
{
    // Using class based composers...
    View::composer(
        'sidebar', 'App\Http\ViewComposers\SidebarComposer'
    );
```

And then composer class, something like this:

```
public function __construct(Requests $requests)
{
    // Dependencies automatically resolved by service container...
    $this->requests = $requests;
}

public function compose(View $view)
{
    $view->with('friendRequests', $this->requests->count());
}
```

Comment: this is the exact answer :)